# Restart chef run after changing chef_environment

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I would like to implement a recipe that would assign node to specific chef environment (early in compilation phase) selected by external condition (in this case Scalr environment variable APP_ENV) and immediately (within existing process tree) restart Chef run

Code like this:

```
if ENV['APP_ENV'] != node['chef_envronment']
  node.normal['chef_envronment'] = ENV['APP_ENV']
  node.save
  Chef::Client.new.run
end
```

won't work as spawned client will see parent and will wait until it exits.. Any ideas? Maybe there a way to force Chef::Client.new.run to ignore lock file?

Answer (score 0):

So a few issues. First, that is not you set a node's environment so this won't actually do anything. Second, calling `node.save` in the middle of a run will generally result in a mismash of partial data ending up on the server depending on where you are running this code. Third, there is no specific way to restart a Chef run. You would have to exit and let the daemon-mode `chef-client` or some other interval run restart it.

```
if ENV['APP_ENV'] != node.chef_environment
  n = Chef::Node.load(node.name)
  n.chef_environment = ENV['APP_ENV']
  n.save
  raise "forcing run to fail to pick up new environment"
end
```

That's still not a bulletproof option, but it is at least better on all three counts.

Comment: The problem with such approach is that it will abort chef run with non-zero (failure) status telling our orchestration (Scalr) that the instance failed during initialization. What I need is to gracefully, within same 'exec' into new chef-run with new environment. Maybe it could be achieved through handlers? I will check.

Comment: As I said, we have no system for this. You could directly re-exec chef-client itself or use a specific exit code to signal that a restart is needed